# Twitter typeahead input and button aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am trying to align my Twitter typeahead autocomplete input and button for a while now, but it keeps looking like this:

[Search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le009.png)

As you see: the search button aligns under the searchbar. It looks like the .twitter-typeahead{ width:100%; } is the one that does this, cause when I remove the class it works good. But in that case the autocomplete won't work, unfortunately.

I've tried several things, like the float:left; and change the widths (but that affects the responsive layout). Probably it's just one simple solution, but I'm not a css-expert and i couldn't find anything here on Stackoverflow.

The complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/u530qvw1/

`.twitter-typeahead {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a right fiddle with the right classes so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flexbox for that (if you don't need to support IE9 :-)):

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <input class="zoeken twitter-typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      <button type="submit" class="search-btn">
          <span class="">Zoeken</span> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
</div>
```

and remove the 100% and the float from twitter-typeahead class and put this to the css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.twitter-typeahead {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marouen! It's almost working. Now the aligning is good, but the form of the typeahead shortens the input form. [Photo](https://postimg.org/image/oyn5k0yuv/) Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @user2721621, it's a little bit hard to check it if I cannot see the code. It looks like you have some css widths on your input field. Can you just post a jsfiddle with the code showing the photo in your last comment?

Comment: Wauw thanks! You were right. It was indeed a width in one of my other CSS-styles, who got overwritten by the typeahead (i guess). It's working now.